# Flutter- How do I archive this center curve of the plus icon using canvas?

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-animation, flutter-bottomnavigation, bottombar

[image]
.

> 

How does this different shape centre the bottom bar menu icon also I want to create a tab change animation as you show in the attached image. I want UI to be the same as the attached image

Thank you